# Android emulation for specific devices

Tags: android, android-emulator

Testing devices using the android emulator can be done through the tool used by google, but is there any way in which to emulate a specific build of a device from a specific vendor, not just the skin?

Answer (score 0):

Only if that device manufacturer ships some sort of special emulator image. [Amazon does for the Kindle series](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/setup.html), for example.

However:

- Few manufacturers do this
- The emulator still does not fully emulate that hardware, simply because the emulator is an emulator (e.g., does not emulate WiFi, even if the hardware has it)